# Why is MSMQ WCF leaving open database transactions?

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

We're using Windows service-hosted WCF service monitoring transactional MSMQ queues with Entity Framework for database operations. While investigating a database-related issue, I noticed that our production services were leaving open transactions after processing their respective message queues.

In the course of troubleshooting, I've trimmed our production code into a simple demo app. I understand that connections are left open and returned to the pool, but feel there shouldn't be open transactions after a message has been processed. This behavior is not present when hosting with an HTTP binding or when instantiating and using the class directly.

Here's all the code for the demo app:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Messaging;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace MsmqTestHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Ensure transacted queue exists
            var queueName = "testqueue";
            var queue = @".\private$\" + queueName;
            if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queue))
                MessageQueue.Create(queue, true);

            // Ensure DB creation
            using (var db = new ProductContext())
            {
                var products = db.Products;
                if (!products.Any())
                {
                    db.Products.Add(new Product {Name = "SomeProduct", Price = 5.00m});
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            // Configure WCF
            var address = "net.msmq://localhost/private/" + queueName;
            var binding = new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.None);
            binding.Security.Transport.MsmqProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

            // Start the host
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SomeService)))
                {
                    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISomeService), binding, new Uri(address));
                    serviceHost.Open();
                    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }).Start();

            // Create a client to add a message to the queue
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<ISomeService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(address));
            var client = factory.CreateChannel();
            client.SomeOperation();
            (client as IClientChannel).Close();
        }
    }

    //WCF service
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.test.local/someservice/", SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
    public interface ISomeService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "SomeOperation", IsOneWay = true)]
        void SomeOperation();
    }

    public class SomeService : ISomeService
    {
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
        public void SomeOperation()
        {
            using (var db = new ProductContext())
            {
                var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault();
                if (product != null)
                {
                    product.Price = 5.00m;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Operation complete");
            }
        }
    }

    //EF objects
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also add the connection string to the App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ProductContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

After running the application, you can look at open transactions on the database with a tool like sp_WhoIsActive and view the (sleeping connection) with an open transaction.

Now change the address binding out for HTTP:

```
var address = "http://localhost:8080/" + queueName;
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
```

Upon running it again, no open transactions are left on the database (but the connection is still open, as expected)

I'm scratching my head on this issue and any assistance is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you set the timeout parameter in your Connection String?

Comment: Can you try actually creating the SQL connection within the message handler? Then passing it into the context. It may be something to do with the connection which is created under the hood not being able to detect the ambient transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Timing out the connection is not desirable as I could just turn off connection pooling and have the same effect (and performance hit). @TomRedfern I tried adding a SqlConnection in the operation and it had no effect. I'm also researching this from a SQL perspective [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151495/mssql-session-has-open-transaction-without-a-transaction)